# What are the effects of linking to a library you do not make function calls to?

Tags: c, linker

I have a make file for a program that links to libdl.so with the following line -ldl.  There are no calls to dlopen or any of the related functions.  What is the effect of linking to this library in this way even though you do not use any of the functions?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I suspect it's the same as not linking to it whatsoever

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to read the documentation for your linker.  From `info ld` on my Linux/ELF/GNU Binutils system (emphasis added):

```
`--as-needed'
`--no-as-needed'
     This option affects ELF DT_NEEDED tags for dynamic libraries
     mentioned on the command line after the `--as-needed' option.
     Normally the linker will add a DT_NEEDED tag for each dynamic
     library mentioned on the command line, regardless of whether the
     library is actually needed or not.  `--as-needed' causes a
     DT_NEEDED tag to only be emitted for a library that satisfies an
     undefined symbol reference from a regular object file or, if the
     library is not found in the DT_NEEDED lists of other libraries
     linked up to that point, an undefined symbol reference from
     another dynamic library.  `--no-as-needed' restores the default
     behaviour.
```

You can check yourself by running `ldd` on a test program.  On a simple test program, I get:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd8305000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f646c669000)
    /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f646c9ca000)
```

However, if I link with `-ldl`, I get this:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff644f1000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb9b1375000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb9b1014000)
    /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb9b1579000)
```

Even though `libdl` isn't used by my program.  However, if I run GCC with `-Wl,--as-needed`, `libdl` will not be linked in.  According to my tests, this only works if `-Wl,--as-needed` is listed on the command line **before** `-ldl`.

**What are the effects?**  It means that your binary won't run on systems without the shared library, even though you don't use it.  It also means that your binary will break if you upgrade the shared library and uninstall the old one.  It's not a big deal because binary compatibility is a bear anyway, but I see no reason not to turn on `-Wl,--as-needed` for projects in general.

Comment: It seems sort of silly that -Wl,--as-needed isn't turned on by default.

Comment: It appears that a number of projects break if this is turned on, as the Gentoo folks discovered (http://bugs.gentoo.org/234710).  The Gentoo package maintainers modify each package as needed to work with the flag turned on.  I don't know WHY the packages break, just that they do.  You can look at the Makefile patches they have and search for `--as-needed`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Looks like there can be issues with `-Wl,--as-needed` if weak symbols are defined:
https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-help/2017-03/msg00080.html

Answer (score 1):

I have coded a small application which uses nothing but STL. It has **8275 bytes** of size without linking to any specific libraries:

```
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00e1e000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0015a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0x0044b000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00741000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0x00250000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00a75000)
```

Now, when I compile it and link it with boost_thread, it grows to **8290 bytes**:

```
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x009d9000)
    libboost_thread.so.1.40.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.40.0 (0x00e59000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x003a3000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0x00bc5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00f8a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0x00110000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0x00bf0000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0x00dd8000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00ba3000)
```

Note that there is no function call on my code to features of boost_thread. However, boost_thread is added anyway as a dependency of my application (as you can see on the output of *ldd*).

Comment: I see something similar when I link to -lssl and don't make any calls to it.  Something grows doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it grows a little bit because boost_thread is added to the dependency list. You can verify this with the help of **ldd**, which shows which shared libraries your application needs to run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Linking to a shared library is different than linking a static library. The main differences were explained already by @Dietrich Epp, but there's another important detail. Shared libraries define functions `void _init()` and `void _fini(void)` which are called upon loading/unloading a shared library; if you don't define them yourself the linker will add default stubs.

Those will be called also if you link your program against a shared library, but don't reference any symbol from the library (and don't add --as-needed linker flag).

Answer (score 0):

Most linkers will simply omit the unused objects from the final binary, exactly as if you hadn't linked with the library in the first place.

Comment: This is not true on, e.g., Linux/ELF.