# C++ app leaking linking with other one

Tags: c++, dll, linker, memory-leaks, libraries

I have a library A developed in c++ in windows. I've made different projects that use this library A and Visual studio doesnt say anything about memory leaks.

I have an application that uses other libraries B. When I mix libraries (A and B), Visual Studio shows me memory leaks. I have only set in the linker properties the .lib of the A libraries, without instantiating any class, and without any includes, but Visual Studio still shows me a memory leak?

What could be the reason because a library that is not instantiated could show memory leaks only linking with it? Is this possible? Perhaps I don't understand at all. What's happening when the application runs? Is some memory for static objects reserved?

regards

Answer (score 1):

I think you partly answer your own question with your last sentence. Because a library can contain global variables or static member variables of included classes (which will be allocated whether you use a class or not) even if you do not use a library just linking against it can have an effect. Further it will depend on whether you are linking statically or dynamically.

See: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411937/what-are-the-effects-of-linking-to-a-library-you-do-not-make-function-calls-to) for a another question on the same topic.