# Confusion about LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE and Meson's counterpart b_asneeded

Tags: c++, cmake, dynamic-linking

From what I gather when Meson performs linking of ELF binaries it trims unneeded shared libraries by default by passing `--as-needed` flag to the linker. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6412134/637669) says that the flag makes linker to go over the libraries list, check if the binary being linked really uses it and if not, remove it from the list.

Now, CMake has the [CMAKE_LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE.html) variable which seemingly does the same as `b_asneeded` in Meson, although unlike Meson it is OFF by default in CMake. However, digging into CMake internals it turns out that CMAKE_LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE actually passes `--no-as-needed` which is a default behavior anyways:

```
% grep -r LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE_FLAG /usr/local/share/cmake/
...
Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:  if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CXX_LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE_FLAG)
Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:    set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE_FLAG "LINKER:--no-as-needed")
```

This confuses me. How would I end up with unused libraries removed when using `CMAKE_LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE`?

Comment: It looks like https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Help/prop_tgt/LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE.rst this option is used to __print__ the unused linker dependencies, not to pass `--as-needed` linker option. In order to _print_ them, `--no-as-needed` is passed to link _all_ libraries and then `ld` is executed to _print_ the unused ones when compiling. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/prop_tgt/LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE.html#prop_tgt:LINK_WHAT_YOU_USE https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmcmd.cxx#L415

Comment: @KamilCuk Your comment seems correct. So it turns out that CMake doesn't an out-of-box switch analogous to Meson's b_asneeded?